# Is there a way to use TouchID for iTunes and App store only?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios, touch-id

I previously asked [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142763/is-there-a-way-to-use-fingerprint-only-for-entering-the-itunes-appstore-passwo) question for iOS 7.  I am on iOS 8 now and in the Settings for Touch ID, there is a specific toggle for `Use Touch ID for iTunes & App Store`.

I turn it on - it tells me that I need to create a passcode (in case Touch ID isn't available).  After that, it makes me enter the passcode to unlock the phone.

Is there a way to use Touch ID exclusively for the iTunes and App Store and also not having a passcode on the device?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you set everything up with a passcode and both Unlock and Store are selected and then toggle off the unlock functionality? If that works, you might be able to remove the passcode, no?

Comment: @bmike Nope...removing the passcode toggles iTunes & App Store off.  Unless I am missing some simple step.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my image being Dutch, but you can disable the unlock functionality easily after setting it up correctly.

[image]

No, you **need** to have a password in case Touch ID doesn't work. There's no way (at least without jailbreak) to get this 'fixed'.

Comment: I'd say the dutch is a bonus :-)

Comment: I tried this very thing...  Did you actually get it to work?  Because for me it still asks to enter a passcode everytime i lock the phone or it goes to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

After each time you reboot the phone, it will demand the unlock code. Only once that has been successfully entered will it then allow TouchID.

Same applies to initial login & also iTunes.

Having TouchID enabled makes it always lock when switched off, there is no grace period for switching it back on within the 'lock after…' period, like devices without TouchID.